# Web Page Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

newbie question.

I've read some of the W3Schools, I also read a lot from other sources on the internet, however I can't find what I need, and I'm sure it's quite simple to you.

I'm using ASP.Net, and I want to add to my website, multiple items, which every item hold a picture, and some other information, including links. I'm pretty sure I don't need to write the code for every item in the HTML source, and I don't know exactly how to implement my this.

The basic idea is that my items will be imported from a Database that I create in visual studio, and I want to style my webpage so they would appear in a certain formation, I thought I might need to use Javascript or CSS for this, hope I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Probably you can use this greate exanple https://github.com/aspnet/musicstore

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. You've stated a goal, but you haven't said what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'd start with Twiiter Bootstrap CSS FMK.

Comment: Yo must also specify if you are using webforms or mvc since the answer might be different in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript isn't some sort of magician that will render all your stuff on its own. However, you can use it to attach a template to every of your items.

What you have to do is :

1. Create a base HTML template for 1 of your item that can be applied to all of them
2. Create a Javascript function that will attach thoses CSS classes and HTML attributes to every element out of your DB (or you could use a templating frameork .. since there's a lot of them I'll let you look for it on Google. It's pretty easy to use)
3. On page load or whatever event you want to bind on, you call your function which will attach the CSS and HTML to every element out of your DB and will render it on your page
4. Enjoy what you've done.

I hope this helps. Good luck ! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll probably delete my question now, mean community... :/